# Showing that $x = \frac{1}{1+e^{-a+bx}}$ has a unique solution

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

My numerical calculations suggest that the equation
$$x = \frac{1}{1+e^{-a+bx}}$$
has a unique solution for any $a,b \in \mathbb R$. How would one go about showing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $y = \dfrac1{1+e^{-a+bx}} - x.$
$$y' = \dfrac{-be^{-a+bx}}{(1+e^{-a+bx})^2} - 1.$$

If $b$ is positive, $y' < 0$, $y$ is strictly decreasing.
Thus $y$ can be zero at most one point and the
original equation can have at most one solution.

If $b$ is negative, the derivative suggests
some possibility of another solution.

A solution exists by IVT because y(1) < 0 < y(0).

Answer (score 1):

(Someday, I'll learn how to include pictures on here.)

Let $r=e^{-a}$ and note that $r$ is positive.

We solve the equation for $e^{bx$}$ to get

$$e^{bx} = \frac{1-x}{rx}.$$

Short answer is "look at the graphs of each side."

The left side is always positive.  The right side is positive only for $0<x<1$.  In that interval its derivative is negative, so it's strictly decreasing.  The right side is either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing.  So there is only one possible intersection point of the two curves.